# express js - pass backend vars/data to angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am new to express js so please bear with me.

I am reading "MEAN Web Development" by Amos Q. Haviv and it is a very good book however, there is a part that baffles me.

In order to send backend vars/data to the client you have to store them in the window object and then use angular js to intercept that data with a service. Something like this:

```
angular.module('users').factory('Authentication', [function() {
  this.user = window.user; //DATA FROM DB

  return {
   user: this.user; //DATA NOW ACCESSIBLE TO THE CLIENT
  }
}]);
```

Is that right?  If that is the only way to do it THAT SUCKS!  Seems very cumbersome to me.

Does anybody out there have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sure sucks.

Implement RESTful architecture and request data from Node.js via an API using Angular [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) or [`$resource`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource).

For regular server to client and bi-directional communication Angular is the wrong answer, since it's based on `HTTP`.  In this case you need to use `WebSocket`.

Comment: ugh, I was afraid someone was going to say that. Thats not a much of a better solution.

Comment: @John How is it not?  This is the gold standard of single page Web apps this day.  Web app is loaded once and then only does data exchange with the server.

Comment: @John Or your question is about regular server to client communication initiated by the server?

Comment: Yes, its more a question about sever to client communication generated by server.  I really don't like the idea of having a MVC for the backend AND frontend for ONE app.

Comment: @John Then Angular is the wrong answer since it's http based.  You need WebSocket.

Comment: If I do go down the RESTful architecture, having my app making all sorts of crazy http calls, wont I run into security issues?  How could I make that more secure?

Comment: @John RESTful architecture by itself is not a security risk.  It all depends on details of your implementation.  The problem is that with RESTful architecture you are using HTTP protocol which means data exchange can be initiated ONLY by the client.

Comment: I see, thank you for getting involved in this discussion.